# How to Refresh Combox After Deleting a Item From It C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

```
dt = GetId1(ClasSType);
string ClassID = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
ncd.DeleteNewNoorWood(ClassID);
typeCb.Refresh();
```

The `TypeCb` is a comboBox control Where I'm having a list of items.
When I delete the item using my `DeleteNewNorthWood()` method the item is getting deleted from the database, however I can still see it on the form.

How should I refresh it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 typeCb.Items.Clear();
 for (int i = 0; i < DataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
 typeCb.Items.Add(nTable.Rows[i][1].ToString());
```

This will work

Answer (score 2):

Specify the datasource again on the combo box

```
typeCb.DataSource = yourDataSource;
```

Comment: dt I have used For getting the class id for deleting Purpose,

Comment: @KiranS, what is your current data source, you need to re-bind it again

Comment: what he is saying is you rebind - fetch the new data and bind again

Comment: @Habib and codingbiz
Ya got it thnk u

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your typeCb.DataSource to an ObservableCollection. This way you don't need refresh manually.